# Boost graph library - distributed adjacency list

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I've been recently trying to implement an algorithm using distributed adjacency lists, as defined in the BGL documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_adjacency_list.html)

I am constantly seeing this error:

```
error: ‘mpi’ is not a member of ‘boost::parallel’
   distributedS<parallel::mpi::bsp_process_group, vecS>,
```

My setup:

Relevant imports:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <boost/graph/use_mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp>
```

My CMakelists.txt

```
## cml

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Parser)
include_directories("src")
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})
add_executable (parserX "src/pparse.cpp" "src/pparse.hpp")
target_link_libraries(parserX ${MPI_LIBRARIES})


if(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(parserX PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endif()

if(MPI_LINK_FLAGS)
  set_target_properties(proteome PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "${MPI_LINK_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

As official boost documentation doesn't provide a single example, where such setting would be presented, I post this question here.

Thank you very much.